# Connecting AVAudioSourceNode to AVAudioSinkNode does not work

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-audio

#### Context

I am writing a signal interpreter using AVAudioEngine which will analyse microphone input. During development, I want to use a default input buffer so I don't have to make noises for the microphone to test my changes.
I am developing using Catalyst.

#### Problem

I am using [AVAudioSinkNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosinknode) to get the sound buffer (the performance is allegedly better than using `.installTap`). I am using (a subclass of) [AVAudioSourceNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosourcenode) to generate a sine wave. When I connect these two together, I expect the sink node's callback to be called, but it is not. Neither is the source node's render block called.

```swift
let engine = AVAudioEngine()

let output = engine.outputNode
let outputFormat = output.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
let sampleRate = Float(outputFormat.sampleRate)

let sineNode440 = AVSineWaveSourceNode(
    frequency: 440,
    amplitude: 1,
    sampleRate: sampleRate
)

let sink = AVAudioSinkNode { _, frameCount, audioBufferList -> OSStatus in
    print("[SINK] + \(frameCount) \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)")
    return noErr
}

engine.attach(sineNode440)
engine.attach(sink)
engine.connect(sineNode440, to: sink, format: nil)

try engine.start()
```

#### Additional tests

If I connect `engine.inputNode` to the sink (i.e., `engine.connect(engine.inputNode, to: sink, format: nil)`), the sink callback is called as expected.

When I connect `sineNode440` to `engine.outputNode`, I can hear the sound and the render block is called as expected.
So both the source and the sink work individually when connected to device input/output, but not together.

#### AVSineWaveSourceNode

Not important to the question but relevant: AVSineWaveSourceNode is based on [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/audio_track_engineering/building_a_signal_generator). This node produces the correct sound when connected to `engine.outputNode`.

```swift
class AVSineWaveSourceNode: AVAudioSourceNode {

    /// We need this separate class to be able to inject the state in the render block.
    class State {
        let amplitude: Float
        let phaseIncrement: Float
        var phase: Float = 0

        init(frequency: Float, amplitude: Float, sampleRate: Float) {
            self.amplitude = amplitude
            phaseIncrement = (2 * .pi / sampleRate) * frequency
        }
    }

    let state: State

    init(frequency: Float, amplitude: Float, sampleRate: Float) {
        let state = State(
            frequency: frequency,
            amplitude: amplitude,
            sampleRate: sampleRate
        )
        self.state = state

        let format = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: Double(sampleRate), channels: 1)!

        super.init(format: format, renderBlock: { isSilence, _, frameCount, audioBufferList -> OSStatus in
            print("[SINE GENERATION \(frequency) - \(frameCount)]")
            let tau = 2 * Float.pi
            let ablPointer = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(audioBufferList)
            for frame in 0..<Int(frameCount) {
                // Get signal value for this frame at time.
                let value = sin(state.phase) * amplitude
                // Advance the phase for the next frame.
                state.phase += state.phaseIncrement
                if state.phase >= tau {
                    state.phase -= tau
                }
                if state.phase < 0.0 {
                    state.phase += tau
                }
                // Set the same value on all channels (due to the inputFormat we have only 1 channel though).
                for buffer in ablPointer {
                    let buf: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float> = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(buffer)
                    buf[frame] = value
                }
            }

            return noErr
        })

        for i in 0..<self.numberOfInputs {
            print("[SINEWAVE \(frequency)] BUS \(i) input format: \(self.inputFormat(forBus: i))")
        }

        for i in 0..<self.numberOfOutputs {
            print("[SINEWAVE \(frequency)] BUS \(i) output format: \(self.outputFormat(forBus: i))")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outputNode` drives the audio processing graph when `AVAudioEngine` is configured normally ("online"). `outputNode` pulls audio from its input node, which pulls audio from its input node(s), etc. When you connect `sineNode` and `sink` to each other without making a connection to `outputNode`, there is nothing attached to an output bus of `sink` or an input bus of `outputNode`, and therefore when the hardware asks for audio from `outputNode` it has nowhere to get it.

If I understand correctly I think you can accomplish what you'd like to do by getting rid of `sink`, connecting `sineNode` to `outputNode`, and running `AVAudioEngine` in [manual rendering mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioengine/2881237-enablemanualrenderingmode). In manual rendering mode you pass a manual render block to receive audio (similar to `AVAudioSinkNode`) and drive the graph manually by calling [renderOffline(_:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioengine/2881253-renderoffline).